# Best way to ensure subscription happened before emitting next value

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm using OAuth 2.0 to retrieve a Token for my User in my Angular Application. I use the popular lib `angular-oauth2-oidc` for handling the OAuth Flow. So in my AppComponent I set up the oAuthService from `angular-oauth2-oidc` and then initiate the oAuth Flow in my Login Component by calling `initCodeFlow()`. The User is redirected to enter his credentials and afterwards he get's redirected to me and I recieve the token in the AppComponent and put it as next token into my DataService TokenSubject.

But now I want to make an API call with that token in the header in my MainPageComponent. So I subscribe in my MainPage to the TokenSubject and when I recieve the Token the code in the subscribe block get's executed.

But what if the token get's send to me quicker than the main page builds up? Then I'm not yet subscribed to the TokenSubject in the Main Page when the next Token value is emitted by the AppComponent. I'm not sure, but my main page sometimes did't open up and I think this is probably the reason.

**What's the best way to make sure that the Main Page is subscribed to the TokenSubject, before I emit the TokenSubject?**

My `AppComponent`:

```
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
...

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    token: Token = {
      access_token: null,
      refresh_token: null
};

constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService,
                private adapterService: AdapterService,
                private dataService: DataService,
                private logger: NGXLogger) {
}

ngOnInit() {
        this.configureOAuthService();
        this.subscribeToOAuthEvents();
    }

configureOAuthService() {
        const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
            issuer: environment.oauthLoginUrl,
            redirectUri: environment.oauthRedirectUrl,
            clientId: environment.apiKey,
            scope: 'openid',
            responseType: 'code',
            showDebugInformation: true,
            disablePKCE: false,
            oidc: true,
            disableAtHashCheck: false,
        };

        this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
        this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
        this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
}

subscribeToOAuthEvents() {
        this.oauthService.events.subscribe(e => {
            if (e.type === 'token_received' || e.type === 'token_refreshed' ) {
                this.storeTokenInDataService();

                const self = this;
                // this will wait for 2 hours minus 30 sec before it refreshes the access token;
                setTimeout(() => { self.refreshToken(self); }, 7_170_000);
            } else if (e.type === 'token_expires') {
                this.logger.log('token_expires, going to refresh');
                this.refreshToken(this);
            } else if (e instanceof OAuthErrorEvent) {
                this.logger.error('OAuth error:', e);
            } else {
                this.logger.log('OAuthEvent:', e);
            }
        });
    }

    storeTokenInDataService() {
        this.token.access_token = this.oauthService.getAccessToken();
        this.token.refresh_token = this.oauthService.getRefreshToken();
        this.dataService.nextToken(this.token);
    }
```

In my Main Page I subscribe to the sharedToken but I#m not sure if that always happens before the Token gets emitted:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('going to get the token from dataService');
  this.dataService.sharedToken
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      tap(token => {
        this.token = token;
        console.log('got Token');
      }),
      switchMap(token => {
        this.headers = this.createHeaders(token.access_token);

        return this.adapterService.getUserInfo(this.headers);
      }))
    .subscribe(UserInfo => {
      this.logger.log('received userInfo : ', userInfo);
      ... 
  });
 }
}
```

In my DataService it looks like this:

```
  private token = new Subject<Token>();
  sharedPToken = this.token ;

  nextToken(token: Token) {
    this.token.next(token);
  }
```

**Update:** The question was solved, my final Main Component looks like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataService.sharedTokenReplaySubject
    .pipe(
      takeLast(1),
      tap(token => {
        this.token = token;
        console.log('got Token');
      }),
      switchMap(token => {
        this.headers = this.createHeaders(token.access_token);

        return this.adapterService.getUserInfo(this.headers);
      }))
    .subscribe(UserInfo => {
      this.logger.log('received userInfo : ', userInfo);
      ... 
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: you can't ensure it with `Subject`.

You could use the RxJS [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) instead. It's a variant of the more general `Subject` you're using. However it can "hold/buffer" specific number of previous emissions and emit to future subscribers immediately upon subscription. In your case you could use buffer 1. It'll hold and emit the last pushed value pushed to it.

```js
private token = new ReplaySubject<Token>(1);  // <-- buffer 1
sharedToken = this.token.asObservable();

nextToken(token: Token) {
  this.token.next(token);
}
```

This way you don't need to worry if the value is pushed to the `token` before or after the subscription to `sharedToken`. The subscription `this.dataService.sharedToken` will get the token even if the value got pushed to `token` before the subscription.

Comment: This works fine! I combined it with `takeLast(1)` to only take the latest token from the replay subject (with buffer 1) and then immediately unsubscribe from it. I updated my question with the final result, using `takeLast(1)` makes sense here, right?

Comment: @GrgKro: I don't think `takeLast` would be good fit here unless you're manually calling `this.token.complete()` somewhere else. If you only wish to use the last emitted value and close the observable you could use `take(1)` or continue using `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` like you were doing and close it in `ngOnDestroy()` hook. Refer here to see what I mean: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7tqrqq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I missed that takeUntil doesn't emit until completion. `take(1)` seems to be the best fitting one.